# Scala: wrapper for Breeze DenseMatrix for column and row referencing

Tags: scala, matrix, scala-breeze

I am new to Scala. Looking at it as an alternative to MATLAB for some applications.

I would like to program in Scala a wrapping class in order to be able to assign column names ("QuantityQ" && "QuantityP" -> Range) and row names (dates -> Range) to Breeze DenseMatrices (http://www.scalanlp.org/) in order to reference columns and rows.

The usage should resemble Python Pandas or Scala Saddle (http://saddle.github.io).
Saddle is very interesting but its usage is limited to 2D matrices. A huge limitation.

---

***My Ideas:***

**Columns:**
I thought a Map would do the job for colums but that may not be the best implementation.

**Rows:**
For rows, I could maintain a separate Breeze vector with timestamps and provide methods that convert dates into timestamps, doing the numbercruncing through Breeze. This comes with a loss of generality as a user may want to give whatever string names to rows.
Concerning dates I use nscala-time (a scala wrapper for joda)?

---

- What are the drawbacks of my implementation?
- Would you design the data structure differently?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have reformulated the question/problem in order to make it more clear. Tnx.

Comment: For anyone visiting this query after it was made years ago: Please see link below. It does not answer anything, really, but it is a discussion related to the question. It's basically a tentative to mimick the Dataset API provided by Spark. https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/470